# How to use macro in a C printf?

Tags: c, linux

Our code has versioning information hardcoded in printf in at least 20 different files like:
`printf("Software version v11.2");` This means changing 20 files everytime there is an update.

Instead i wish to use a macro and #include it in a common.h file, such that version update is just changing one macro, that's all.

I tried something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VERSION "v11.2"
int main()
{
  printf("Trying to print macro: ", VERSION);
}
```

But this style of "string""string" works in Java not in C.
Any ideas how to accomplish it?

We will use the gcc for compilation.

NOTE: **The macro is also used in some typical *.rc files, where we can't use a variable, and somewhere these rc files are parsed using SQL query. So we can't use variables like char ver[]="v11.2"**

Comment: You can use `puts("Software version" VERSION);`, where a string concatenation will occur between string literals. I can't think of any case where `puts` is dangerous with the usage above, while someone crazy can go and put format string into `VERSION` macro and mess the thing up with `printf`.

Comment: you could encapsulate the whole printf in a function to make it even more DRY, i.e. print_version() in case you version info gets more complex at a later date

Comment: "string" "string" works fine in C ... that's where Java got it. But you put a comma between the strings.

Comment: Its C basic question on printf. Please go through the man page of printf and do some hands on before you ask here. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Viswesn: Yes it's too basic, but still did you notice how many people gave a wrong answer? By the way..FYI..downvoting others's questions leads to loss of one's own reputation point too. Did you know that? Might be not, seems like you are new in this forum.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Most of the people gave a wrong answer mainly because they jump to answer your question to get more points in there account :( and more over you too worried about your point rather than specifying that you got answer. Points are just number so don't go behind point. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VERSION "v11.2"
int main()
{
  // Let printf insert the string when doing the output.
  printf("Trying to print macro: %s\n", VERSION);
  // Let the compiler concatenate the strings.
  puts("Trying to print macro: " VERSION);
  // Let the compiler concatenate the strings, can be assigned to a variable.
  const char buf[] = "Trying to print macro: " VERSION;
  puts(buf);
}
```

Comment: I thought to use a variable, but we can't because many of the files are *.rc file, where they only use a macro. And some are C or CPP file.

Comment: @kingsmasher1  Why are you talking about variables? VERSION is a macro here. Both these solutions work (provided that VERSION doesn't contain a % ... if it does, the second solution yields undefined behavior; puts would be better, as noted by nhahtdh above). You should accept the answer.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 If we are talking about resource strings, you can only use the string concatenation variant. Problem could (will?) be: Visual Studio resource editor might not like rc files with string concatenation. Another solution would be removing the version sub string from all rc strings and building the complete strings at runtime. I am using FormatMessage for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Please remove the later one `printf("Trying to print macro: " VERSION);` this does not work. I just tested it now. Yesterday askd the question and rushed home from office due to a headache, so could not test :)

Comment: @kingsmasher1: It works if the macro is a string. [This](https://gist.github.com/3312158) compiles and works just fine (with GCC 4).

Comment: @kingsmasher1: edited my answer back again and added the assignment case you added to my post. The code compiles on MSVC10.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Trying to print macro: %s", VERSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is a string, `%s` should work.

```
int main()
{
  printf("Trying to print macro: %s", VERSION);
}
```

Comment: I thought to use a variable, but we can't because many of the files are *.rc file, where they only use a macro. And some are C or CPP file

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Why do you keep talking about variables? The given code works fine if VERSION is a macro that expands to a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#define PRINT(format,args...)\
\
    do { \
        printf(" your data...");\
        } \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: Er, I suggest that you read the question more carefully, for starters.